# Php mysql update to same record value and fix with round function

Tags: php, mysql

Hello i have some values in column like : 8106.8499999999985

so i want fix it to be like : 8106.85

i tried to do the following

```
mysql_query("Update statements set Balance = '".round("Balance",2)."' where CHAR_LENGTH(Balance) > 8");
```

I wanted to follow same way of : update statements set Balance = Balance + 1 where...

any solution

Comment: Why not do this at output time?

Comment: like select > while >  then update ? , i would like to do that only in one line if possible :D

Comment: But why reduce the usefulness of your data like this, for no good reason? What if you have to add or subtract values? (and consider storing the value in a correct data type)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
UPDATE statements SET Balance = ROUND(Balance, 2);
```

There's no need to use PHP with concatenation, just run it as:

```
mysql_query("UPDATE statements SET Balance = ROUND(Balance, 2)");
```

**Aside:** `mysql_*` is insecure. You should be using `mysqli_*`.

---

To round to 2 decimal places unless the last decimal place is a zero, presuming you're using a numeric data type (not `VARCHAR`):

```
UPDATE statements SET Balance = IF(RIGHT(ROUND(Balance, 2), 1) = 0, ROUND(Balance, 1), ROUND(Balance, 2));
```

If you're using `VARCHAR`, change `0` to `'0'` (and then fix the data type using `ALTER TABLE`).

Here's [a demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/48957/1).

Comment: if value like : 29259.199999999997 it should be : 29259.2 but with ROund of mysql results is : 29259.20  :P i know its same value but with php it give me what i want : 29259.2

Comment: Your question says "fix it to be like : 8106.85" (i.e. with 2 decimal places). If you only want 1 decimal place, change the `2` to a `1` in the query.

Comment: yep but with round of php , it give me 29259.2 not 29259.20 and that what i looking for it ,even if round (value,2) with php : 29259.2